# how to make sure that a file will be closed at the end of the run

Tags: c++

Suppose someone wrote a method that opens a certain file and forgets to close it in some cases. Given this method, can I make sure that the file is closed **without** changing the code of the original method?

The only option I see is to write a method that wraps the original method, but this is only possible if the file is defined outside the original method, right? Otherwise it's lost forever...

Comment: Which method u r calling for file open ?

Comment: C++ has functions, not methods.

Comment: If the method can "forget" to close the file, then it's not using a C++ file stream. What is it using instead?

Comment: @Saladin Akara - maybe he never got a good answer. Only answering questions where you think you'll get upvotes or an accept is kind of like treating stackoverflow as a game instead of a useful resource for others.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since this is C++, I would expect that the I/O streams library (`std::ifstream` and friends) would be used, not the legacy C I/O library.  In that case, yes, the file will be closed because the stream is closed by the stream object's destructor.

If you are using the legacy C API, then no, you're out of luck.

In my opinion, the best answer to an interview question like this is to point out the real flaw in the code--managing resources manually--and to suggest the correct solution:  use automatic resource management ("Resource Acquisition is Initialization" or "Scope-Bound Resource Management").

Comment: RAII according to Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization

Comment: @James: If C API is used, _fcloseall() function can be used to close all the open files.

Comment: @bjskishore123:  I don't know where `_fcloseall()` comes from, but it isn't part of the C standard library.  Even so, given its name, I don't see how that would be much use in any real program:  its use would indicate papering over of serious program errors.

Comment: @James: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxfsw25t(VS.80).aspx 
Its present in stdio.h

Comment: @bjskishore123:  It may well be present in Microsoft's C library implementation as a vendor-specific addition.  It is not part of the C standard library.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that if the wrapper doesn't somehow get a reference to the opened file, it may be difficult to close it.  However, the operating system might provide a means to get a list of open files, and you could then find the one you need to close.

However, note that most (practically all) operating systems take care of closing files when the application exits, so you don't need to worry about a file being left open indefinitely after the program stops.  (This may or may not be a reasonable answer to the question you were given, which seems incredibly vague and ambiguous.)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using C function for file open, you can use `_fcloseall` function for closing all the opened files.

If you are using C++, Like James suggested, stream destructor should take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

Which environment are you in? You can always check the file descriptors opened by the process and close them forcefully.

Under linux you can use the lsof command to list open files for a process. Do it once before the method and once after the method to detect newly opened files. Hopefully you aren't fighting some multithreaded legacy beast.